# Quotes at end of inline query

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I recently looked through some old code for database access layer. I found some inline queries of the following form:

```
string query = "SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL3 = " + colvalue + "";
```

I was wondering why the developer had appended the query with double quotes at the end. Is this convention or does it have any significance?

Comment: No, it has no effect - possibly a remnant from a previously larger where clause. But better still would be to parameterize the variable `colvalue` - this has query plan caching benefits, as well as a good habit to get into to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt make any difference at all...

neither does it help to prevent sql-injection

use command parameters or stored procedures to prevent sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was some extra query between `""` like `where` etc. However it does not affect the functionality.

It is always a good practice to use parameters for this kind of work.